# VBA UDF Excel 2010 #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

I have read the threads that are about UDF #VALUE errors and it seems that either I do not know enough about VBA to be able to use them or the problem I have is not the same.

Either way, I am trying to make a UDF to calculate the number of months in an age in the format YY:MM based on a formula I created that did the same.

```
Function TOTALMONTHS(YearsMonths As String)
Colonz = WorksheetFunction.Find(":", YearsMonths)
Yearz = Left(YearsMonths, Colonz - 1)
Monthz = Mid(YearsMonths, Colonz + 1, Lengthz - Colonz)
Lengthz = Len(YearsMonths)
TOTALMONTHS = Yearz * 12 + Monthz
End Function
```

The above code returns a #VALUE error when implemented in Excel 2010.

Any assistance on what mistake(s) I have made would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit:

I am trying to and an If block to cater for ages containing ">" at the beginning.
For example, 8:6 and >8:6. I think I maybe be getting a false positive on the search=1 result at the beginning but cannot figure out why.

```
Function TOTALMONTHS(YearsMonths As String) As Integer
If WorksheetFunction.Search(">", YearsMonths) = 1 Then
Greaterz = 2
Else
Greaterz = 1
End If
Colonz = WorksheetFunction.Find(":", YearsMonths)
Yearz = Mid(YearsMonths, Greaterz, Colonz - Greaterz)
monthz = Right(YearsMonths, Len(YearsMonths) - Colonz)
TOTALMONTHS = Yearz * 12 + monthz
End Function
```

I have no Idea how to do the "If" bit and also cannot figure out how to put code in a comment below... thanks in advance!!

SOLVED using the answer below - thank you so much!

And this is the final code to allow for ":" or "." delimiters and ">" symbols as well:

```
Function TOTALMONTHS(YearsMonths As String) As Integer

Dim Colonz As Integer, Yearz As Integer, monthz As Integer, Greaterz As Integer

' check if the stings consists of ">" sign
If InStr(YearsMonths, ">") >= 1 Then
    Greaterz = 2
Else
    Greaterz = 1
End If

' check position of ":" or "." sign
If InStr(YearsMonths, ":") >= 1 Then
    Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ":")
Else
    Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ".")
End If

Yearz = Mid(YearsMonths, Greaterz, Colonz - Greaterz)
monthz = Right(YearsMonths, Len(YearsMonths) - Colonz)
TOTALMONTHS = Yearz * 12 + monthz

End Function
```

Comment: `Lengthz` is 0 in the line `Monthz = Mid(YearsMonths, Colonz + 1, Lengthz - Colonz)` because you haven't set the value yet.

Comment: Don't you want it to return something ? like `Function TOTALMONTHS(YearsMonths As String) as Long` ?

Comment: I want it to return an integer amount of months- thank you I will try those 2 now!

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! It works!

Comment: @GLDevlin you can answer your own post, just write it down with your working code

Comment: one modification (if you want to make) you can use the following functions to get the same result: `Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ":")` , then `Yearz = Left(YearsMonths, Colonz - 1)` , and last `monthz = Right(YearsMonths, Len(YearsMonths) - Colonz)`. And you can remove the fourth line `Lengthz = Len(YearsMonths)`

Comment: I have edited above to show where I am with the code now. I edited the code to include your changes and also I am trying to add an IF then else function. Thank you!

Comment: @GLDevlin edit your post, and show all types of ages typed as Strings that you want your function to handle. Example: "22:06", what else ? how does a string `>` looks like ?

Comment: Thank you Shai Rado, updated now!

Comment: @GLDevlin try my edited code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the updated UDF code below:

```
Function TOTALMONTHS(YearsMonths As String) As Integer

Dim Colonz As Integer, Yearz As Integer, monthz As Integer, Greaterz As Integer

' check if the stings consists of ">" sign
If InStr(YearsMonths, ">") >= 1 Then
    Greaterz = 2
Else
    Greaterz = 1
End If

' check position of ":" sign
Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ":")

Yearz = Mid(YearsMonths, Greaterz, Colonz - Greaterz)
monthz = Right(YearsMonths, Len(YearsMonths) - Colonz)
TOTALMONTHS = Yearz * 12 + monthz

End Function
```

Below you can find the samples of data I tested this UDF code with:

(keep in mind, that cells in columns B and E need to be formatted as Text)

[image]

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much for all your help! It now works perfectly! Your advice was very helpful and I feel I learnt a lot!